# Switch Between wordpress website and asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, iis, web-hosting

I am new to word press and asp.net web hosting.So I have a issue below.

I have a website which has mainly front end in word press and back end in asp.net. There are some page in the front-end that will be in asp.net like sign in and Sign-Up
Now my issue is how can I switch from a word press website to asp.net or visa-versa website with same domain name.

Please suggest any Idea how can I proceed.

Comment: Such combinations are not wise. Why do you want to do so?

Comment: Hi @VinodKumar existing website including home page etc. are in word press and they can be dynamically changed from wordpress back end. 
And page like Sign In and Signup should be in asp.net. after login all the back-end system is in asp.net.

Comment: OK. Then a possible solution is to host both PHP and .NET applications individually (either in a same system with different ports or different systems). Use HTML for sign-in and sign-up make ajax calls to your .NET server. Thus finally, your HTML and PHP resides on your desired URL and .NET application on some other URL (sub url or url with port number). End user will not have to know where .NET is hosted. Does this help?

Comment: Basically, you can not host two servers (apache and IIS) on same port.

Comment: for all the pages that i need to create should be HTML page?
I can't navigate between wordpress and asp.net application

Comment: Is there any other solution present to do so?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77791/discussion-between-vinod-kumar-and-g-s-bhangal).

Answer (score 1):

Hosting web applications require web servers. Since in your case **IIS** for **.NET** and **Apache** for **wordpress/php**. You will not be able to run IIS and Apache parallelly by listening to same PORT.

So one possible solution could be,

1. To have sign-in and sign-up page on wordpress (either in the form on html or PHP).
2. Make ajax calls to .NET to authenticate or register the user.

Thus, they run as two different applications and end user will not know any difference in URL or anything.

Hope this helps.